# How Report Builder connects to Progress DB?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

We are using XenApp to open Report Builder. Currently it's connected to the production server and connects with progress db.

Now we are in a process of moving to new production server.We need to make sure what are all the configuration files used to connect with report builder with that particuler production server.

Where are the server and db details defined in the report builder?

Are there any confiquration files used for Report Builder?

Current Progress version in production 9.1.

Comment: What version of Progress are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into your short cut/batch-file starting the report builder and refer to:

- Chapter 2 of the Report Builder Tutorial
- Chapter 1 of the Report Builder Users Guide

*Download pdfs from links below*

The settings can basically reside either in files (standard extensions .ini and .pf) or in the registry of your server (given it's a windows server which it most likely is since you're running report builder on it).

[Report Builder Tutorial](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1800.9-1e-report-builder-tutorial.aspx)
[Report Builder Users Guide](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1799.9-1e-report-builder-user-s-guide.aspx)